# Link in page feed Graph API android

Tags: android, facebook-graph-api

I want to get the image and the link in a Facebook post.

[image]

I'm using the Graph API but I can't understand how to do it:

`/* make the API call */
new GraphRequest(
    AccessToken.getCurrentAccessToken(),
    "/{post-id}",
    null,
    HttpMethod.GET,
    new GraphRequest.Callback() {
        public void onCompleted(GraphResponse response) {
            /* handle the result */
        }
    }
).executeAsync();`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at

- https://developers.facebook.com/docs/android/graph#userdata
- https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.5/post

If you have an actual `post_id`, this would result in a call like this:

```
String postId = "21898300328_10154057125545329";

GraphRequest request = GraphRequest.newGraphPathRequest(
        accessToken,
        postId, 
        new GraphRequest.GraphJSONObjectCallback() {
            @Override
            public void onCompleted(
                   JSONObject object,
                   GraphResponse response) {
                // Application code
            }
        });

Bundle parameters = new Bundle();
parameters.putString("fields", "id,message,link,attachments{media{image}}");

request.setParameters(parameters);
request.executeAsync();
```